# Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=1

Tags: react-native, expo, zustand

I'm using AsyncStorage in zustand which is used by expo to store some data (large size >2MB) on device, and then read it with the following code

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { logger, LOG_LEVEL } from "../utils/general/logger";
export const checkAsyncStorageMemoryUsage = async (setAsyncStorageMemoryUsage) => {
    try {
        const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
        let totalSize = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            const key = keys[i];
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
            const valueSize = value ? value.length * 2 : 0;
            totalSize += key.length * 2 + valueSize;
        }
        const totalSizeInMB = (totalSize / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2);
        console.log(`AsyncStorage memory usage: ${totalSizeInMB} MB`);
        logger(`AsyncStorage memory usage: ${totalSizeInMB} MB`, LOG_LEVEL.INFO);
        setAsyncStorageMemoryUsage(totalSizeInMB);
    } catch (error) {
        logger(`Error checking AsyncStorage memory usage: ${error}`, LOG_LEVEL.ERROR);
    }
};
```

The following error appears when I try to get data usage
and display for the purpose of clearing the cache:

```
Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=1
```

The alternative approach I tried didn't work. the below one is alternative approach

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { logger, LOG_LEVEL } from "../utils/general/logger";

const BATCH_SIZE = 5;
const MAX_RETRIES = 5;

export const checkAsyncStorageMemoryUsage = async (setAsyncStorageMemoryUsage) => {
    try {
        const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();

        let totalSize = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i += BATCH_SIZE) {
            const batchKeys = keys.slice(i, i + BATCH_SIZE);

            let batchValues = [];
            let retryCount = 0;

            while (retryCount < MAX_RETRIES) {
                try {
                    batchValues = await Promise.all(batchKeys.map(key => AsyncStorage.getItem(key)));
                    break; 
                } catch (error) {
                    retryCount++;
                    console.warn(`Retrying batch retrieval (${retryCount}/${MAX_RETRIES}) due to error: ${error}`);
                }
            }

            const batchData = batchKeys.map((key, j) => ({
                key,
                value: batchValues[j],
            }));

            for (const { key, value } of batchData) {
                const valueSize = value ? value.length * 2 : 0;
                totalSize += key.length * 2 + valueSize;
            }
        }

        const totalSizeInMB = (totalSize / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2);
        console.log(`AsyncStorage memory usage: ${totalSizeInMB} MB`);
        logger(`AsyncStorage memory usage: ${totalSizeInMB} MB`, LOG_LEVEL.INFO);
        setAsyncStorageMemoryUsage(totalSizeInMB);
    } catch (error) {
        logger(`Error checking AsyncStorage memory usage: ${error}`, LOG_LEVEL.ERROR);
    }
};
```

I added some batch, but the asycstorage value automatically changed to zero after 4 MB. However, I do not want to set zero. I want the total storage to be calculated and displayed.  once I click clear cache then only i need to set zero. Can you suggest any other solution which I can try to resolve this issue? I have used zustand with asycStorage.

here is my clear storage code

```
export const clearPersistedStore = async () => {

    try {

        await AsyncStorage.removeItem("storage");

        resetStore();

    } catch (error) {

        logger("Error removing item:" + error, LOG_LEVEL.ERROR);

    }

};
```

Comment: use a local DB instead of AyncStorage.. it's a persisted layer not meant for storing huge chunks of data imo. Maybe have a look at realm db for react-native.

Comment: Instead of using a single key , Use multiple keys to store multiple values.

Comment: I tried multiple stores with multiple keys and values still getting this error